# Difference between DBUM and DBAT

Tags: database, oim

Can someone explain in detail what's the difference between *User Management* and *Application Table*?

Both are referring to the same target database or how are they different?

I totally could not understand the concept.

Answer (score 1):

DBUM manages Database Users (as schema owners) while DBAT manages tables with users/accounts used by some applications